# Cloud9 IDE issue for Python

Tags: python, cloud9

I have written python program in IDE however, I get the following error for importing Pandas in python. Just importing pandas in the program.

import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘pandas’

However, I have also installed Anaconda and with that, I used Jupyter Notebook to run the same program and it was successful.
How can I solve this issue in IDE?

Comment: `pip install pandas`

Comment: You have pandas installed in Anaconda virtual eviroment. You need to install pandas globaly or create your own virtualenv where is your python script and install pandas inside this virtualenv.